# Clickonce installer installing SQL Server 2016 Express fails with errorcode -2061893613, what does error code -2061893613 mean?

Tags: sql-server, clickonce, silent-installer

ClickOnce install with integrated SQL Server Express install fails with error code -2061893613 and the following in the log:

> Result of checks for command 'SqlExpress2016\BOOTSTRAP.EXE' is 'Install'
>
> 'SQL Server 2016 Express - xxxxxx' RunCheck result: Install Needed
>
> Verifying file integrity of C:\Users\xxxxx\AppData\Local\Temp\VSD7E54.tmp\SqlExpress2016\BOOTSTRAP.EXE
> Verifying file hash
> Installing using command 'C:\Users\xxxxxxx\AppData\Local\Temp\VSD7E54.tmp\SqlExpress2016\BOOTSTRAP.EXE' and parameters '/ACTION=Install ........'
>
> Process exited with code -2061893613
> Status of package 'SQL Server 2016 Express - xxxxx' after install is 'InstallFailed'

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue on a SQL 2014. Challenge was that the SQL install was a prerequisite of an application that had a hard coded sa password that could not be easily changed.

The work around was to do a manual install of SQL and give sa a password that matched the policy. Once installed I could go into SSMS and change the properties on the sa account so it would not enforce password policy (open security folder, logins and right click on sa and select properties) by unchecking the box. Then change the password to the one the application install uses.

Yes, the next version of the application will not only use a stronger password, but will also be using an up to date version of SQL.

Answer (score 0):

;TLDR, company had a policy with password strength requirements that weren't met with the default SA password used in the installation script.

Got the log files from "C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\130\Setup Bootstrap\Log" on the failing machine and it was a dead giveaway in Summary.txt:

```
Overall summary:
  Final result:                  Failed: see details below
  Exit code (Decimal):           -2061893613
  Exit facility code:            1306
  Exit error code:               19
  Exit message:                  The specified sa password does not meet strong password requirements. For more information about strong password requirements, see "Database Engine Configuration - Account Provisioning" in Setup Help or in %SQL_PRODUCT_SHORT_NAME% Books Online.
```